# old-style cast while using htons

Tags: c++

I have a section of code that makes use of `htons` and I get this error during compilation.

> error: use of old-style cast [-Werror=old-style-cast]

The line is:

```
mFarEnd.sin_port = htons( g_DolCommsUdpPort );
```

where `g_DolCommsUdpPort` is defined as:

```
static uint16_t const  g_DolCommsUdpPort = 43775;
```

I have tried the following C++ cast without success:

```
mFarEnd.sin_port = static_cast< unsigned short int >(htons( Bti::Atlas::UDPPorts::g_DolCommsUdpPort ) );
```

Comment: This post is unreadable. Why did you ignore the live preview and blindly hit "ask that question" without a moment's thought?

Comment: I fixed it, but seriously, there's a preview right there, staring at you.

Comment: What is the definition of `htons`? Try preprocessing the source, I bet the cast is inside a macro.

Answer (score 3):

My bet is that `htons` is a macro expanding to an expression with casts and shifts. The benefit of a macro, as opposed to an inline function, is that it works in a constant expression. (C++11 enables suitable inline functions in constants.)

All the inline-function-like macros in the C and POSIX libraries are also required to exist as `extern` functions. You can defeat the macro and call the function instead by parenthesizing its name:

```
mFarEnd.sin_port = (htons)( g_DolCommsUdpPort );
```

It's also tempting to `#undef htons`, but this is illegal (undefined behavior). For example, the implementation could internally be using the macro to generate a constant, in some totally unrelated macro.